# External Page Login using POST Form

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to login a external page by using a POST Form as -

```
<form id="login-form" action="https://www.mydomain.in/login/" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li><label for="id_username">Login ID</label><input id="id_username" class="text_box_small" type="text" name="username" maxlength="75" />
            <div class="error_mssg">&nbsp;</div>
        </li>
        <li><label for="id_password">Password</label><input id="id_password" class="text_box_small" type="password" name="password" />
            <div id="error_msg" class="error_mssg">&nbsp;</div>
        </li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /><span id="email_wait_loader_id" class="email_wait_loader" style="display: none;"> </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Here when I try putting my username and password I got a message as -

{"success": {"message": "Logged in successfully"}}

But it did not redirect to the new page after login.

Comment: You need to store cookies/ sessions to stay logged in , use curl for it

Comment: I am using this code in the Joomla 2.5 Module custom html. Can u please help me out. I am new to PHP and Joomla

Comment: I can surely help you with curl  but i am not familiar with joomla

Comment: Thanks Sir, I can integrate with the Joomla. Please help me with the CURL

Comment: Posted the answer ,   don't forget  to   accept  the answer if  it helped  you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");    
$post = array(
    'username' =>$Username,
    'password' =>$Password
            // Add As many parameters as you need
    );
$post_data = http_build_query($post);
$ch = curl_init('https://www.mydomain/login/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);// This stores the cookie , you can use it later  if you have to make more request which  requires user to be loged in
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Some Usefull URLs

`http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php`

`http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php`

`http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php`

Comment: and another problem is how can I know about the successful or falier in login

Comment: while testing simply  put echo  before curl_exec($ch); and what ydo you mean by simple form ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do something like:

```
<form id="login-form" action="https://www.mydomain.in/login/" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:var self=this;$.ajax({ url:$(self).attr('action'), type:'json', success:function(response){ if(response.success != undefined){ document.location.href='http://www.sometarget.com/page/after/login';}else{alert('Login failed');}}});return false;">
```

This required jQuery at '$'

Basically the form will submit via ajax and redirect on success.. or throw alert.

Comment: I tried changing the above <form> tag with your code but I got the same result. i wrote the whole code inside the Joomla Module custom Html.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript alone:

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var self=this;
    $.ajax({ 
        url : $(self).attr('action'), 
        type : 'json', 
        success : function(response){ 
            if(response.success != undefined){
                document.location.href = 'http://www.sometarget.com/page/after/login'; 
            }else{
                alert('Login failed');
            }
        }
    });
});
```